# edittext with multi style text

Tags: android, html, android-edittext, spannablestring

I need to add multiple styles for text in my edittext, after searching I have found two ways

1- using this and it is working for me

```
str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.correct_email_color)), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

2- using HTML format, and I need to be able to use this to add padding and margin to my text :

```
str.setSpan(new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(String.format(EMAIL_HTML_FORMAT, "ffA9F5BC" , splittedEmail[i]))), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

but the second way is not working, can any one help here ??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think you have to use 
**android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan**

For e.g:-

**str.setSpan(new android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(30, 0), 0, s.length(), 0);**

Look into the following..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/LeadingMarginSpan.html

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "<body>By clicking Sign Up i agree with Facebook<b>Terms and Conditions</b> and <b>Privacy Policy</b></body>";
        Spanned spanned1 = Html.fromHtml(text);

        tvTerms.setText(spanned1);
```

above code is just snippest to use style through html tag hope it wll help you to achieve your requirement that how to give style through html tag in android